# SharePoint Online: Is it possible to follow a term?

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-set, follow

You can follow sites in SharePoint Online and then see news posts from them on your homepage. Is it possible not to follow the whole site, but follow only some types of news?

We created a term set and some terms and added a managed metadata column to the SitePages library. Now we are using this column to tag / categorize our news posts and news links.

Is it possible to allow the user to follow one or more of the terms from this termset and then see news / get the auto-news digest only for news assigned to this categories?

Answer (score 0):

For your questions:

Q1：The users with edit permission can post the news. Per my knowledge, currently the OOTB of SharePoint Online cannot meet this requirement. For the time being, it does not support only following certain types of news.

Q2：Term set is mostly used to search and metadata tasks, you could refer to this article for more information:

[Assign roles and permissions to manage term sets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/assign-roles-and-permissions-to-manage-term-sets)

Q3：As [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automatically-sending-news-post-digests-b930b579-0de5-4c67-86f0-de64b87c45e3) mentioned, usually automatically sent emails are determined by Microsoft Graph,

- How is relevant news determined?

  Using the power of Microsoft Graph, the following criteria is used to
  determine when news is relevant for a user:

  When someone in the user's direct management chain publishes a news
  post

  When someone a user works closely with publishes a news post